# Is there a non-pdb way to enter Python interpreter at a given line?

Tags: python

Is there a way to cause a python script to enter the interpreter at a given line? I know I can use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to begin debugging at a certain line, but that means all the pdb commands may get in the way.

Is there a way to kick into the regular interpreter (or ipython) outside of pdb?

Comment: Lots of dupes for this one. Search "enter python interpreter programatically" or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I did a few searches but didn't find that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is `code.interact`:

```
import code
code.interact(local={**globals(), **locals()})
```